# Error when weak-linking StoreKit framework on iPhone

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, weak-linking

I am trying to add In App Purchase support to my app. I would like the app to still be able to support OS2.2.1, but IAP are not available unless the OS version is 3.0 or higher.

I have tried weak-linking the StoreKit framework. Basically, I have StoreKit.framework added to frameworks, but not in Link Binary With Libraries in the target, and have added weak_framework -StoreKite to the other flags line, as per the Apple instructions. Now when I run the app on OS2.2.1 it crashes in _read_images before the main function is even executed. I really need to support 2.2.1 and I know other apps do it. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar issue with the iAd Framework. Well sort of.  I thought it was the iAd Framework but when I completely commented out all the new code and removed the framework it was still crashing.

It worked on the Simulator just not on the device.  I found `posix_spawn("/var/mobile/Applications/...", ...): Permission denied` in the Console logs.

This lead me to believe that it was some type of code-signing error.  I deleted the app from the device and re-installed. This launched the app successfully.

It appears there was some remnants of the version installed on the device from the released version did not allow the debug version to install correctly.